# Add onClick event to Svg elements using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to integrate this svg tooth chart in my React project :
https://codepen.io/johnstuif/pen/JdOXWa?editors=1111
and then add onClick event on every tooth to trigger an alert.
i used `document.querySelector("g").addEventListener("click", () => alert("clicked"))` but it seems that i did something wrong.
Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't click on a g, it isn't something that's rendered. You can only click on shapes or text.

Comment: document.querySelector("polygon").addEventListener("click", () => alert("clicked")) works for me provided I click on the first polygon in the document.

Comment: still didn't work, i think I'm going with the response below, to wrap everything in div

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to wrap every tooth in div where you can add onClick event directly in react. Or even better, make it as component!

You're using a powerfull tool that let's you build amazing stuff, no needs for going back to JavaScript dom manipulation when you have react :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you give me one code example on 1 tooth so i could duplicate?I'm new to React